# How do I pluralize the <address> tag in Watir-Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

In watir-webdriver you can do the following to collect all instances of an `<a>` tag:

```
browser.as(:class => 'foo').text
```

However, when I try this on an `<address>` tag like so

```
browser.addresss(:class => 'foo').text
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `addresss'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct pluralization is "addresses".

You can find just about all the tags by looking at the ruby doc for [Container](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Container).

Comment: Yes, I just realized this. Very intuitive. I kind of jumped the gun on asking this question really.